# retrieved data from sqlite database and displaying it on grouped table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

hii every one

i am brand new to obj c, i have did a sample project where i have 2 screens on the first screen i have six text fields & 2 buttons named save and ViewData ,on click of save data which is entere d in the text field will be get saved in the sqliteData Base ,& on click of the button ViewData it will navigate to a new screen which has a grouped table view, here i am trying to display the data which is stored in the sqlite ,in the grouped table view i have 6 sections  i am using following code to display the data in grouped table view,problem is grouped table view is displaing only the last data which is entered ih the text field,,but i need to display all the data which enterd should be shown under that section

```
appDelegate = (iICS_testAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    for(int intVar=0;intVar < [appDelegate.arrObjects count];intVar++)
    {
    insertUpdateDelete *InsertRecord = [appDelegate.arrObjects objectAtIndex:intVar];

    NSLog(@"InsertRecord:%@",InsertRecord);




    NSMutableArray *arrTemp1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:InsertRecord.strsixth,nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrTemp2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:InsertRecord.strfifth,nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrTemp3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:InsertRecord.strFourth,nil];

    NSMutableArray *arrTemp4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:InsertRecord.strLogin,nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrTemp5 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:InsertRecord.strMiddleName,nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrTemp6 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:InsertRecord.strFirstName,nil];


    NSMutableDictionary *temp =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:arrTemp1,@"Item Name",arrTemp2,@"Manufacturer",arrTemp3,@"Weight of Item",arrTemp4,@"Num of Item",arrTemp5,@"Price of Item",arrTemp6,@"MFG Date",nil];

    self.tableContents =temp;
    [temp release];
    NSLog(@"table %@",self.tableContents);
    NSLog(@"table with Keys %@",[self.tableContents allKeys]);
    self.sortedKeys =[[self.tableContents allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSLog(@"sorted %@",self.sortedKeys);



    [arrTemp1 release];
    [arrTemp2 release];
    [arrTemp3 release];

    [arrTemp4 release];
    [arrTemp5 release];
    [arrTemp6 release];
    }
```

here im assigning the text for the row

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //insertUpdateDelete *InsertRecord = [appDelegate.arrObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];


    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView 
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    //cell.textLabel.text = [appDelegate.arrObjects objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];




    return cell;
}
```

thanks in advance!

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZYAl.png) is  my snapshopt of grouped table view. I need  the data which is entered through the text field shoul be viewed under particular section

Comment: Do you want to display the keys of your "temp" dictionary as title in section?

Comment: what ever i enter through the text field all those data should be displayed in the grouped view,,but i am getting only last enterd record (as shown in the snapshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution for only the last data is displaying,**

Instead of `NSArray` use `NSMutableArray`.

**Solution for wrong field values,**

Your problem may be in insertion itself,

```
 NSArray *arrTemp1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:InsertRecord.strsixth,nil];
 NSArray *arrTemp2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:InsertRecord.strfifth,nil];
```

You are inserting price value into date field, i think so. Please check that.

Change your code as,

```
NSMutableArray *arrTemp1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrTemp2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrTemp3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrTemp4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrTemp5 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrTemp6 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int intVar=0;intVar < [appDelegate.arrObjects count];intVar++)
    {
    insertUpdateDelete *InsertRecord = [appDelegate.arrObjects objectAtIndex:intVar];

    NSLog(@"InsertRecord:%@",InsertRecord);

    [arrTemp1 addObject:InsertRecord.strsixth];
    [arrTemp2 addObject:InsertRecord.strfifth];
    [arrTemp3 addObject:InsertRecord.strFourth];
    [arrTemp4 addObject:InsertRecord.strLogin];
    [arrTemp5 addObject:InsertRecord.strMiddleName];
    [arrTemp6 addObject:InsertRecord.strMiddleName];
    }
 NSDictionary *temp =[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:arrTemp1,@"Item Name",arrTemp2,@"Manufacturer",arrTemp3,@"Weight of Item",arrTemp4,@"Num of Item",arrTemp5,@"Price of Item",arrTemp6,@"MFG Date",nil];

    self.tableContents =temp;
    [temp release];
    NSLog(@"table %@",self.tableContents);
    NSLog(@"table with Keys %@",[self.tableContents allKeys]);
    self.sortedKeys =[[self.tableContents allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSLog(@"sorted %@",self.sortedKeys);

    [arrTemp1 release];
    [arrTemp2 release];
    [arrTemp3 release];
    [arrTemp4 release];
    [arrTemp5 release];
    [arrTemp6 release];
```

Comment: that is fine , i can change tat one. that is not my problem.iam getting only the last entered value instead of all the records

Comment: did you check the return value of numberOfRowsForSection?

Comment: @sameer post the code of - (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section method

Comment: @KingofBliss  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section]];
 return [listData count];
}

Comment: Instead of NSArray *listData use NSMutableArray *listData

Comment: i tried its still not working,it ll be very help ful if u give any related code or tutorial